# Datetime format not working with slashes Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui

My web application has support for multiple datetime formats, namely `yyyy-MM-dd`, `yyyy.MM.dd`, `dd/MM/yyyy` and `MM/dd/yyyy`. The two first ones work perfectly, however, when I use the other two formats, the slashes are replaced with dashes in the initial print, which makes them fail validation. However, if I choose a date, it comes out with the correct (chosen) format.

I am using culture sv-SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *suspect* (with no experience of Kendo UI, but with experience of other date/time APIs) that "/" is being treated as "the culture-specific date separator". If you want "exactly a forward slash, regardless of culture" you may need to escape it.

How the escaping is performed will depend on the library, but often you'd just use quotes, e.g.

```
dd'/'MM'/'yyyy
MM'/'dd'/'yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Jon notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15615589/67392) in his answer this is about `/` being a special character in .NET [custom date formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator).

When working with Kendo this is confusing because it does not use `/` as a [special character](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting).

Using separate format strings client and server side should be the answer, but unfortunately in [Telerik UI for MVC](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/introduction) (which uses Kendo on the client side) a single format string is used both client and server side with the  MVC helpers for Kendo.

For example on a server with a date format "dd-MM-yyyy" (set in Windows regional settings), and a view model:

```
    [Display(Name="Date")]
    [UIHint("Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = Constants.DateFormat, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

(`Constants.DateFormat` is "dd/MM/yyyy") then having an editor template ("Date.cshtml"):

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m)
```

leads to an initial date display "29-05-2015" and JavaScript errors as it cannot be parsed.

As a work around using

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m)
              .ParseFormats(new[] { "dd-MM-yyyy", Constants.DateFormat}))
```

the format in the generated HTML is wrong, but the JavaScript will at least be able to understand it. (This should make use of `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator` to build the alternative format dynamically of course.)